# SQL Sum a distinct set of rows without duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that is selecting data from two tables. However, I want to have the name only appear once. It is appearing twice even with the distinct. My query is pasted below along with the current results and the desired results.

The data in the employeetimesheets table is pasted as well with the data corresponding to rowid '4'. You can see it added the 0.25 together but that's it  How do I query the sum of unique IDs without having the extra rows? Any help is most appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.rowid, 
                a.employee, 
                Sum(b.value) AS TotalHours 
FROM   employees a 
       INNER JOIN employeetimesheets b 
               ON a.rowid = b.empid 
WHERE  b.title = '50001310-01' 
GROUP  BY a.rowid, 
          a.employee, 
          b.value
```

Current Results

```
4   Aa Bus  0.5
4   Aa Bus  1.5
95  Lh Wr   7.5
95  Lh Wr   8
```

Desired Results

```
4   Aa Bus  2.0
95  Lh Wr   15.5
```

Data in the EmployeetimeSheets for RowId '4'

```
14579   4   2015-11-21  2015-11-18  50001310-01 F oy    0.25    2015-11-20 10:58:54.897 16  NULL    1
14580   4   2015-11-21  2015-11-19  50001310-01 F oy    0.25    2015-11-20 10:58:54.900 16  NULL    1
14785   4   2015-11-21  2015-11-21  50001310-01 F oy    1.5     2015-11-21 12:57:22.273 16  NULL    1
```

Comment: exclude `b.value` from `group by` as that is the column being aggregated. Also, you don't need `distinct`

Comment: `group by employee`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.rowid,
       a.employee, 
       Sum(b.value) AS TotalHours 
FROM   employees a 
       INNER JOIN employeetimesheets b 
               ON a.rowid = b.empid 
WHERE  b.title = '50001310-01' 
GROUP  BY a.rowid, a.employee
```